# Offset in API calls in Azure Data Factory

Tags: api, rest, pagination, azure-data-factory

I am using ADF to retrieve data from a REST API and loading into an SQL DB. The problem I have is that the endpoints in the API return a max of 50 records per page.

I'm trying to use the built-in pagination in ADF by setting Pagination rules with QueryParameters, {offset} using range and the max value.

Some endpoints in the API does return total rows in the call. So I could possibly use this somehow to make the Copy Data activity dynamic.

The relative URL i use is:

```
@concat(
pipeline().parameters.relative_url,
'?offset={offset}'
)
```

And the {offset} in Pagination Rules is set up as:

```
@concat(
'RANGE:0:',
activity('LookUp_Total').output.firstRow.Total,
':50')
```

The problem I encounter is with endpoints where the total is larger than 50 I get duplicates. So if the total is for example 76 I still get 100 records.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use Offset Pagination, and for that it requires two variables

   i.e, a `limit` and an `offset`.
- **limit** is for the number of records to return.
- **offset** is for the number of rows to skip first.
- So, it needs you to dynamically alter the offset value, and gradually increasing till records are empty.

You can walk through the full syntax and code [here](https://www.carryoncloud.co.uk/azure-data-factory-offset-pagination/).

SO - [Azure Data Factory Pagination with offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022282/azure-data-factory-pagination-with-offset).